# Rshiny : displaying chart when clicking on a polygon

Tags: r, shiny, data-visualization, shinyapps

I'm a Rshiny newbie very eager to learn but right now I'm facing an issue I cannot overcome alone and I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me out ! :)

My problem is (I guess) quite simple:

I have created a map with my polygons and I've managed to display some basic informations when I click on them [(have a look on here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YslYM.jpg) but I have no idea how to add a barplot (for example) below my map for each polygon I click.

Could someone help me on how doing that please ? (after hours and hours of attempts my eyesballs are really about to pop out of their sockets !!!)

Many thanks in advance !

Romain

My code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(devtools)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

communes <- readOGR("G:/Ateliers/Projet/communes.shp")
commmunes@data

nom_commune                 INSEE  Variable_1   Variable_2  Variable_3 area_sqkm
1    AUZEVILLE-TOLOSANE     31035         289     8.727212    9.336384  6.979758
2      CASTANET-TOLOSAN     31113          85     4.384877    8.891650  8.460724
3                LABEGE     31254         288     5.047406    2.031651  7.663404
4            PECHBUSQUE     31411         443     6.577743    8.120896  3.099422
5 RAMONVILLE-SAINT-AGNE     31446          95     2.601305    8.909278  6.236784
> 




ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap"))


  #### SERVEUR R #####


  bins <- c(3,3.5,6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.5)
  pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", domain = communes$area_sqkm, bins = bins) 
  labels <- sprintf(
    "<strong>%s</strong><br/>%g km2",
    communes$nom_commun, communes$area_sqkm
  ) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mymap<-renderLeaflet(
    leaflet(communes) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)
      ) %>%
      setView(1.50, 43.54, zoom = 12) %>%
      addTiles()  %>% 
      addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(area_sqkm),
                  weight = 2,
                  opacity = 1,
                  color = "white",
                  dashArray = "3",
                  fillOpacity = 0.7,
                  highlight = highlightOptions(
                    weight = 5,
                    color = "#666",
                    dashArray = "",
                    fillOpacity = 0.7,
                    bringToFront = TRUE),
                  label = labels,
                  labelOptions = labelOptions(
                    style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
                    textsize = "15px",
                    direction = "auto")) %>% 
      addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~area_sqkm, opacity = 0.7, title = NULL,
                position = "bottomright")
  )
}     


shinyApp(ui = ui, server=server)
```

The data I would like to display in my barplots are the variable 1,2 and 3 :

```
data <- read.csv("G:/Ateliers/Projet/communes.csv", sep=";")
data

nom_commune                 INSEE  Variable_1   Variable_2  Variable_3 area_sqkm
1    AUZEVILLE-TOLOSANE     31035         289     8.727212    9.336384  6.979758
2      CASTANET-TOLOSAN     31113          85     4.384877    8.891650  8.460724
3                LABEGE     31254         288     5.047406    2.031651  7.663404
4            PECHBUSQUE     31411         443     6.577743    8.120896  3.099422
5 RAMONVILLE-SAINT-AGNE     31446          95     2.601305    8.909278  6.236784
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example shiny app with other data, since I do not have access to your shape data for the map. I believe this might do what you need it to do and can be adapted for your needs.

I would create a `reactiveVal` to store the `id` of the polygon region that is clicked on (this variable stores `input$mymap_shape_click$id`). You data used in `addPolygons` should have an `id` to reference.

In your plot (or in a separate `reactive` expression), you can filter the data based on the `reactiveVal` containing the `id`.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

arcgis_data = st_read("http://data.phl.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/bc2b2e8e356742568e43b0128c344d03_0.geojson")

arcgis_data$id <- 1:nrow(arcgis_data)  ## Add an 'id' value to each shape

plot_data <- read.table(text =
"id nom_commune                 INSEE  Variable_1   Variable_2  Variable_3 area_sqkm
1    AUZEVILLE-TOLOSANE     31035         289     8.727212    9.336384  6.979758
2      CASTANET-TOLOSAN     31113          85     4.384877    8.891650  8.460724
3                LABEGE     31254         288     5.047406    2.031651  7.663404
4            PECHBUSQUE     31411         443     6.577743    8.120896  3.099422
5 RAMONVILLE-SAINT-AGNE     31446          95     2.601305    8.909278  6.236784", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F
) 

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput(outputId = "mymap"),
  plotOutput(outputId = "myplot")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  ## use reactive value to store the id from observing the shape click
  rv <- reactiveVal()

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addPolygons(data = arcgis_data %>% slice(1:5), layerId = ~id) %>% 
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron")
  })

  observeEvent(input$mymap_shape_click, {
    rv(input$mymap_shape_click$id)
  })

  ## you can now plot your plot based on the id of region selected
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    plot_data %>%
      filter(id == rv()) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Variable"), names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = Variable, y = Value)) +
        geom_col()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Edit**: For your uploaded data, you don't need to add a separate `id` for `communes`. Instead, you could match by name (`nom_commune`). You can use that in your `layerId` instead. This looks like it should work. I did take out some of the additional label information as this appeared to be missing from the .shp file I downloaded.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

communes <- readOGR("communes_ok.shp")

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput(outputId = "mymap"),
  plotOutput(outputId = "myplot")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  ## use reactive values to store the id from observing the shape click
  rv <- reactiveVal()

  output$mymap<-renderLeaflet(
    leaflet(communes) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
      setView(1.50, 43.54, zoom = 12) %>%
      addTiles()  %>% 
      addPolygons(fillColor = "blue",
                  weight = 2,
                  opacity = 1,
                  color = "white",
                  dashArray = "3",
                  fillOpacity = 0.3,
                  highlight = highlightOptions(
                    weight = 5,
                    color = "#666",
                    dashArray = "",
                    fillOpacity = 0.7,
                    bringToFront = TRUE),
                  layerId = ~nm_cmmn)
  )

  observeEvent(input$mymap_shape_click, {
    rv(input$mymap_shape_click$id)
  })

  ## you can now 'output' your generated data however you want
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(rv())) return (NULL)
    plot_data %>%
      filter(nom_commune == rv()) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Variable"), names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = Variable, y = Value)) +
        geom_col()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Sorry for the wrong file ! Here is the good one:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wlSAwgz3TRATg2KoBEo9LVdkBmnFSKJ7
I've erased the variables from the shapefile to make it more easier to read

Comment: See bottom of my edited answer. This works on my setup without any errors. Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thank you so much Ben, it worked perfectly now !!! Damn I could sleep peacefully now !! :D

Many thanks again !!!

Comment: *bonne nouvelle! et bonne chance!*

Comment: Merci beaucoup ! :D